# Evaluating a pandas series with a for loop and nested inequality statement

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I'm attempting to run a for loop through a pandas dataframe and apply a logic expression to a column in each of the elements of the dataframe. My code compiles without error, but there is no output.

Example code:

```
for i in df:
    if df['value'].all() >= 0.0 and df['value'].all() < 0.05:
        print df['value']
```

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to see whether all elements in a column are satisfying that logical expression, this can be used:

```
np.logical_and(df['value'] >= 0.0, df['value'] < 0.05).all()
```

This will return a single `True` or `False`.

By the way, I don't see how the `for` loop is being used. Since in the current format, the same code will run in each iteration.

Comment: It's possible I'm using the for loop in error, but I'm attempting to use the for loop to iterate through each csv in the dataframe. The desired output are the values that satisfy the inequality statement. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to iterate over the columns of the data frame, you can use `df.iloc[:,i]` instead of `df['value']`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

`.all()` is going to return `True` or `False` and so based on the order of your checks, you're filtering everything out. I assume what you actually want is `(df['value'] >= 0.0).all() and (df['value'] < 0.05).all()`.

EDIT: You're also not actually iterating over the columns. Replace `'value'` with `i`.

```
In [11]: df = pd.DataFrame([np.arange(0, 0.04, 0.01), np.arange(0, 4, 1)]).T

In [12]: df
Out[12]:
      0    1
0  0.00  0.0
1  0.01  1.0
2  0.02  2.0
3  0.03  3.0

In [13]: for c in df:
    ...:     if (df[c] >= 0.0).all() and (df[c] < 0.05).all():
    ...:         print df[c]
    ...:
0    0.00
1    0.01
2    0.02
3    0.03
Name: 0, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I gave this a shot, but still no output.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the result you are looking for?

```
print(df.loc[(df['value'] >= 0.0) & (df['value'] < 0.05), 'value'])
```

For just the values, throw this in:

```
print(df.loc[(df['value'] >= 0.0) & (df['value'] < 0.05), 'value'].values)
```

or

```
print(list(df.loc[(df['value'] >= 0.0) & (df['value'] < 0.05), 'value']))
```

for a list of the values

Comment: This returns each element of each csv where the conditional statement is true in the 'value' column, rather than just the value of the 'value' column, but I can make it work. Thanks.

Comment: @tscoffey added some options to return the value in the 'value' column